# What is the most straightforward way to restrict pipeline stages to a specific shared resource?

Tags: jenkins, embedded, jenkins-pipeline

We have an existing Jenkins install that is testing firmware running on an embedded tart. The multi-stage pipeline looks something like: *Checkout* -> *Build* -> *Download* -> *Smoke tests* -> *Unit tests*. This is working great, except it takes 9 hours to run the pipeline. To speed things up and also to test different target variants we have added 3 more targets to the system (UUT#1, #2, and so on).

My question is, what is the most straightforward way to allow the parallelization happen while also restricting the suites to UUTs with specific properties. For example, our *Unit tests* contain about 10 different suites (suite1 suite2 and so on), and what I’d like to do is spread those out amongst the 4 UUTs (thus having 4 suites running at a time) but restrict the execution this way:

- Suite1 can only run on a UUT that has ‘USB’
- Suite2 can only run on a UUT that has ‘LCD-display’
- Suite3 can run anywhere

.. and so on, then my UUTs might have properties like:

- UUT#1 ‘USB LCD-display’
- UUT#2 ‘Ethernet’
- UUT#3 ‘RS-232 USB’

Etc.

Reading about agents, it seems that a `label` on an agent may allow this, but agents seem to carry a lot of overhead and I’m not sure if they’re appropriate.

Long-time Jenkins user, but this is the first time I’ve ever attempted anything this complicated and pipelines are a new concept for me.

Comment: Do [lockable resources](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/lockable-resources/) suit your needs? These are very lightweight and you can filter by label.

Comment: @zett42 Yes, that might just do the trick! Thank you I will try the lockable resources plugin and report back with my results.

Comment: @zett42 I finally got a chance to try lockable resources, and it seems there's a quirk with the `lock(label: 'ethernet')` form used in Declarative Pipeline syntax: you have to supply a `resource` parameter when you supply a `label` parameter, which seems to defeat the purpose of labels. Found an example of locking by label here [link](https://jenkinsci.github.io/job-dsl-plugin/#method/javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.jobs.IvyJob.lockableResources) but that seems to be using the scripted pipeline syntax. Anyone know of a way to use `lock(label: 'xxx')` without supplying a `resource` name?

Comment: I should have posted the actual error I was getting: `WorkflowScript: 30: Missing required parameter: "resource" @ line 30, column 25. lock(label: 'ethernet') {`. The documentation (link in first comment) explicitly says _Either a resource or a label need to be specified_.

Comment: I have used it in declarative aswell as scripted pipeline. In either case I only had to specify a label, not a resource, which adheres to the documentation. It might be interesting to know that you can use `lock` as a stage option in declarative pipeline, which is missing from the documentation. I can post some examples as an answer when I'm back at work tomorrow.

Comment: BTW, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56911603/7571258) suggests that you can specify `null` for the resource argument, although I don't remember having to use that. Maybe that's because of my use of `lock` as a stage option.

Comment: Thank you! I located an example of using `lock(..)` as a stage option, and now I don't get any errors. But .. the lock doesn't seem to be doing what I expected. I have two stages (inside a `parallel` block) and each of those stages does a `lock(label: 'ethernet')`. I have two Global resources defined, each with the word `ethernet` in its label string. I have 4 executors, so I am _expecting_ the two stages to execute at the same time but one always waits until the first completes. If I add a third stage (with no `lock(..)` option) it _does_ run in parallel. I'm confused.

Comment: Wait, I missed the `quantity` parameter to `lock(..)`. It seems if you omit `quantity` it assumes **all** and that wasn't what I wanted. If I change the lock call to `lock(label: 'ethernet', quantity: 1)` I get the behaviour I was expecting. @zett42 if you want to weigh in with your observations I'll accept your answer and we're done here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A straightforward way is to use the [Lockable Resources plugin](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/lockable-resources/).

This can be used as a step as well as a stage option (undocumented). The latter comes in handy if you have nested stages which all depend on the resource to be locked.

**Stage option in declarative pipeline**

```groovy
pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage('Test') {
            options {
                // Lock a single resource from all resources labeled 'mylabel'
                lock( label: 'mylabel', 
                      quantity: 1,
                      variable: 'MyResourceName' )
            }
            steps { // or 'parallel' or 'stages'
                echo "Locked resource $MyResourceName"
                sleep 10
                echo "Resource will be unlocked after this stage"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Step in scripted pipeline**

```groovy
node {
    stage('Test') {
        lock( label: 'mylabel', 
              quantity: 1,
              variable: 'MyResourceName' ) {

            echo "Locked resource $MyResourceName"
            sleep 10
            echo "Resource will be unlocked after this stage"
        }
    }
}
```

**Caveats**

- If `lock` is used as a step in declarative pipeline, you may get an error:

  > Missing required parameter: "resource"

  This seems to be a little bug in argument checking. According to the documentation, you only need to specify either `resource` or `label` parameter. Simply pass `null` as the value for this parameter.
- If parameter `quantity` is not specified, all resources that match the given label will be locked.

Comment: Nice summary of the solution and the issues that may be encountered getting there. Thanks!